# Dynamically update label of edges in Cytoscape.js graph

Tags: javascript, html, cytoscape

I'm working with a Cytoscape.js graph and I would like to dynamically update labels of edges:

Here is an example of my graph:

```js
window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),

    layout: {
         name: 'preset'
    },

    style: fetch('cy-style.json').then(function(res){
      return res.json();
    }),

    elements: [
        // nodes
        { data: { id:'box_1', label:'BOX_1', type:'app'}, position: {x:21,y:32}},
        { data: { id:'box_2', label:'BOX_2', type:'app'}, position: {x:46,y:44}},

        // edges
        { data: { id: 'box1_to_box2', source: 'box1', target: 'box2', label: '' }, }
     ]
  });
```

It's a very simple graph with two nodes and one edge between them.

I would like to dynamically update the label of the edge `box1_to_box2`. I know how to get the element 'label' but I don't know how to update it. I've tried with `.innerHTML` but it doesn't work. I guess it's because it's not `html` ?

```js
function updatelabel(id, label) {

    console.log(cy.getElementById(id).data("label")) // <-- I have the label
    cy.getElementById(id).data("label").innerHTML = label // <-- doesn't work

}
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```js
var cy = window.cy
cy.$('#'+id).css({
    content: ''+label
});
```